# SQL Помещение запроса в функцию PL/SQL

Tags: sql, функции, oracle, plsql

Есть SQL-запрос, который определяет максимальное и минимальное время между событиями:

```
SELECT CONCAT(person.NAME, ' ', person.PATRONYMIC) AS Worker, MIN(DATEDIFF(SDATE,   LDATE)+1) AS mindiff, MAX(DATEDIFF(SDATE, LDATE)+1) AS maxdiff
    FROM (SELECT SDATE, LAG(SDATE)OVER(ORDER BY SDATE) AS LDATE
    FROM schedule_
    WHERE PERSON_1 = 3 OR PERSON_2 = 3) AS rest, person
    WHERE LDATE IS NOT NULL AND person.ID=3
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо на основе этого запроса создать функцию PL/SQL, которая должна возвращать курсор с результатом.
Синтаксис Pl/SQL знаю весьма поверхностно, можете помочь со структурой запроса? Что должно быть написано после `DECLARE`, и что нужно поменять в самом запросе, когда его в функцию вставляешь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Необходимо возвращать результат в виде полей первого скриншота от `person.id`?

Comment: в задании не указано, просто сказано определить максимальное и минимальное время между дежурствами, и вернуть курсор с результатом.